# Wilcard on day table vs time partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to understand if there is a difference in big query (in the cost or possibility of requesting for example) between :

- Create one table per day (like my_table_2018_02_06)
- Create a time partitioned table (my-table with time partition by day).

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short explanation:** querying multiple tables using Wildcard Tables was the proposed alternative for when BigQuery did not have a partition mechanism available. The natural evolution was to include the feature of Partitioned Table, and currently there is an alpha release consisting in column-based time partitioning, i.e. letting the user define which column (having a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type) will be used for the partitioning.

So currently BigQuery engineers are working in adding more new features to table partitioning, instead of the legacy Wildcard Tables methodology, then I'd suggest that you work with them.

---

**Long explanation:** you are comparing two approaches that in fact are used with the same purpose, but which have different implications:

- ***Wildcard Tables:*** some time ago, when table partitioning was not a feature supported by Big Query, Wildcard Tables was the way to query multiple tables using concise SQL queries. A Wildcard Table represents the union of all the tables that match the wildcard expression specified in the SQL statement. However, [Wildcard Tables have some limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations), such as:

  - Do not support views.
  - Do not support cached results (queries containing wildcard tables are billed every time they are run, even if the "cached results" option is checked).
  - Only work with native BigQuery storage (cannot work with external tables [Bigtable, Storage or Drive]).
  - Only available in standard SQL.
- ***Partitioned Tables:*** these are unique tables that are divided into segments, split by date. There is a lot of documentation regarding [how to work with Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), and regarding the pricing, each partition in a Partitioned Table is considered an independent entity, so if a partition was not updated for the last 90 days, this data will be considered long-term and therefore will be billed with the appropriate discount (as would happen with a normal table). Finally, Partitioned Tables are here to stay, so there are more incoming features to them, such as column-based partitioning, which is [currently in alpha](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages), and you can follow its status in [this Public Issue Tracker post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65440943). On the other hand, there are also [some current limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#partitioned_table_limits) to be considered:

  - Maximum of 2500 partitions per Partitioned Table.
  - Maximum of 2000 partition updates per table per day.
  - Maximum of 50 partition updates every 10 seconds.

So in general, it would be advisable to work with **Partitioned Tables** over multiple tables using Wildcard Tables. However, you should always consider your use case and see which one of the possibilities meets your requirements better.

Comment: Ok. Perfect answer.

Comment: Why partitioned tables are not compatible with decorators if the two features are the future ? Is it only because it's under development ?

Comment: The thing is that [table decorators are currently unsupported in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators).

Comment: Not for now, but support is planned. And even if Decorators was supported in Standard SQL, partition table is not compatible with decorators, isn't it ?

Comment: We need decorators for some requests. And I think that it can be a blocking point to use partitionned table.

Comment: It is correct that right now table decorators are not compatible with Partitioned Tables (even if you are using Legacy SQL). Probably that is because both functionalities overlap in most of the cases, and you wouldn't need to use decorators if you already have a table that is partitioned by dated. Maybe there is a specific use case where it makes sense (maybe yours, as you state that you would need both things at the same time), but in general, one would replace the other.

Comment: In my mind, i can request one hour of data and pay only for that with decorators but not with partionned table isnt it ?

Comment: You are right. But if your use case is to request data in hourly chunks, why would you want to partition it on a daily basis with Partitioned Tables?

Comment: Because on last week data, we want to make some analytics on hour base. And on the global data (a few month retention), we want to make daily analytics...

Comment: Thanks again for all your answer, you have a good knowledge of big query and it's awesome.

Comment: If that is your use case, I am afraid that currently this is not supported. In any case, thanks to you for clarifying your use case, and I hope you can make a good use of BQ for your service!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add to your decision criteria here is caching and usage of legacy vs standard SQL.
Since the syntax in standard SQL for selecting multiple tables uses a wild card there is no way for the query result to be cached.

Interestingly, the query result would have been cached if legacy SQL was used. Just converting the query to standard SQL would disable caching.
This may be important to consider, at least in some cases more than others.

Thank you,
Hazem

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a time partition, but one can benefit from both worlds - wildcard "partitions" and real partitions to slice the data even further. Below is an example where we first use the data suffix to select only table holding data from that particular date, then we use actual partitioning within the table to limit the amount of data scanned even further.

Create first partitioned table with data suffix

```
 CREATE TABLE `test_2021-01-05` (x INT64, y INT64)
 PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(y, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 500, 1));
 insert `test_2021-01-05` (x,y) values (5,1);
 insert `test_2021-01-05` (x,y) values (5,2);
 insert `test_2021-01-05` (x,y) values (5,3);
```

Create second partitioned table with data suffix

```
 CREATE TABLE `test_2021-01-04` (x INT64, y INT64)
 PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(y, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 500, 1));
 insert `test_2021-01-04` (x,y) values (4,1);
 insert `test_2021-01-04` (x,y) values (4,2);
```

Select all the data from both tables using wildcard notation, 80B of data is the whole test set

```
 select * from `test_*`
 -- 80B, all the data
```

Just select data from one table, which is like partitioning on date

```
 select * from `test_*`
 where _TABLE_SUFFIX = "2021-01-05"
 -- 48B
```

Select data both from one table(where I am interested in one date) and only from one partition

```
 select * from `test_*`
 where _TABLE_SUFFIX = "2021-01-05"
 and y = 1
 -- 16B, that was the goal
```

Select data just from one partition from all the tables

```
 select * from `test_*`
 where y = 1
 -- 32B, only one partition from both tables
```

The ultimate goal was to limit the data scanned when reading, thus reducing the cost and increasing performance.

Comment: Actually the suffix should be more like YYYYMMDD format rather than presented YYYY-MM-DD as per GCP naming convention. Using the advised format makes it more readable in GUI as one  rather than multiple separate tables.