# BigQuery - What is the difference between Wildcard and partitionned tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, wildcard

We have to make a choice between this two types of storage in google Bigquery to store timestamped records and from the official docs, we can't find out what are the differences between partitioned tables and wildcards in term of querying time.

As I can see, one can use the column_PARTITIONTIME to query a wildcard table.. Is that mean that wildcard are also partitioned tables?

The question here is about a look under the hood of how bigquery stores data in both table types?

Comment: "As I can see, one can use the column _PARTITIONTIME to query a wildcard table." No, this is not true. How is this post different from your previous question?

Comment: @ElliottBrossarda what previous question ?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused since the posts were so close together. I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641302/wilcard-on-day-table-vs-time-partition (very similar question posted yesterday).